# sh to check if an image exists in Openstack

Tags: openstack

Is there a way to check if an image created by glance below exists in Openstack by its name "myimage" using shell script?

```
glance image-create --name "myimage" --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare --is-public True --progress < myimage.qcow2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this command in shell script to check whether "myimage" already exist in glnace.

```
glance image-list | grep myimage
```

It will return matched image names if image exists, otherwise you will get zero results.

**Edit**

```
#!/bin/sh
image="myimage"
if glance image-list | grep $image > /dev/null
then
    echo "$image already exists"
else
    echo "$image does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: thanks, can you write the complete sh script for the checking as i am not familiar with its grammar?